# Check if multiple files exist in Java

Tags: java, file-exists

I have already read through the topics with similar issues, but have not really found a sufficient answer.

I have following issue:
I am developing a larger Java program and want to create a class or method that simply when the program starts, tests whether images and txt files from res exist. Otherwise there will be an exception.

My main problem is that I do not know how to manage all those multiple files at once.

Maybe someone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Considered `java.io.File` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not checking files in the first place, but classpath resources, ie resources loaded via classloaders APIs like `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`. Both APIs return `null` when the resource can't be found without throwing any Exception (that will likely be thrown later in the program by some other API)

The code to check thus is as simple as this function

```
@Deprecated
private void isAppPackagedCorrectly(String res) {
  if (getClass().getResource(res) == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Missing resource " + res);
  }
}
```

that can be used in a loop. In the provided code fragment I marked the API as deprecated because you'll likely **don't want to affect the startup of the application** with a packaging check. Just get your build process right once, and it won't fail randomly.

Two more random advices:

1. The leading forward slash `/` has a special meaning in constructing the absolute resource name. [Check the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).
2. I always immediately check that the resource is available with a bit of Guava code: `Preconditions.checkNotNull(getClass().getResource(res))`